# BeagleBoard xM with ubuntu 12.04 and opencv slow with face detection

Tags: 12.04, opencv, detect, beagleboard

I have an issue and I would appreciate it if someone could help. I am running ubuntu 12.04 on a beagleboard xm. I have also installed opencv. Now I need to run an application which performs face, eyes and smile detection with a webcam. I am having a hard time with this because the image I get from the camera as well as the detection are very slow and exactly the opposite of real time. I know that probably I need a strongest hardware. My problem is that I am using this board for my thesis. My teacher gave it to me and now I am trying to find even the slightest improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Run fewer services - do `service --status-all`, (or `ps -ef`) and, for each running service:

1. Determine what the service does - [search Ubuntu manpages here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com), and decide if it is needed for your use of the system. For example, `apache2` is probably not needed (YMMV)
2. For each service you decide you don't need, you can stop it one time via `sudo service servicename stop`. If your system still works, consider stopping the service permanently, which begins with finding out how and where the service is started with `grep -l servicename /etc/init/* /etc/init.d/* /etc/rc.local`

Use `top` (and `man top`) to find out what is competing for your resources.

Read  `info coreutils 'nice invocation'`, `man nice`, `man renice` to see how to run processes with higher priority (less niceness).

Find less resource-intensive ways of performing your task.